# which coordinate system the normal vector calculated from height map in?

Tags: opengl, textures, shader, heightmap

I have read a lot of material about heightmap and normal map, and have many questions:

### We can generate a normal map from heightmap:

If we have in the S and T direction:

```
S(i,j)= <1,0,aH(i+1,j)−aH(i−1,j)>
T(i,j)= <0,1,aH(i,j+1)−aH(i,j−1)>
```

then we can calculate normal value N:

```
N(i,j)= (S(i,j) x T(i,j))normalize()
```

then we map (Nx,Ny,Nz) to (r,g,b) this is the method we use to generate normal map from heightmap.

I tried this with several heightmap and diffuse map(convert the diffuse to grayscale as heightmap). Simple ones can provide relative good normal map. Once the image gets more complex, the result is very bad.

My questions are:

- Which coordinate system is this normal vector in?

  I feel it is just at the surface of the object and points out to the normal. Is this the so-called 'TBN' space?

  But there's no T and B information occurred here.
- If t is the tangent space, then for different triangles, we will have different t, so different triangle would have a different T/B/N vector?
- How do I calculate TBN from normal map? I'm a little confused reading the book and look at this matrix:

  ```
  s1,t1 = < s1 − s0,t1 − t0 >
  s2,t2 = < s2 − s0,t2 − t0 >

     | Tx Ty Tz |              | s1 t1 | | Q1x Q1y Q1z |
     | Bx By Bz | = inverse of | s2 t2 | | Q2x Q2y Q2z |
  ```

  What does this s2 and s1 stands for, I know (Q1x Q1y Q1z), are they the (x,y,z) also (r,g,b) value from the normal map, does s2 and s1 stands for the (x,y) location, the pixel location on the normal map?

  [image]

Comment: I guess there are some major misunderstandings: TBN is not calculated from a normalmap. The tangent space only depends on the geometry (with the texture coordinates (s, t)). I'm not sure I could explain the whole problems in the length of an SO answer though. You might want to check the explanation here: https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/129939/messing_with_tangent_space.php

Comment: thanks, nice article. I got some concepts explained: every triangle has its own TBN coordinate system. And a better understanding of the matrix calculation process. Though still wondering the way to create normal map.

Comment: The way you describe the calculation looks good to me. If it is not working, I suggest you ask a new question, describe exactly what you are doing (including code) and show input+output image where the result is not good.

Comment: First, I feel the normal map generated from heightmap compared with the one that accompanies with the model has lost some small detail even some filter is used to enhance the calculation. Second, I think that there's only one tangent direction, the fastest increasing or decreasing direction, but turns out this is gradient, not tangent vector, so we can choose TB randomly, such as in the calculation it is aligned with uv. am I right? Thanks again.